# Vista Serial programmatically

Tags: windows-vista

How do I obtain the serial number of the installed Vista system?
Also is there a tool that does the same thing so I can verify MY results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick list of tools:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm

http://magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/

http://techblissonline.com/find-product-key-cd-ley-windows-vista-xp-office-2007-sql-server-produkey/